Track User Engagement on Facebook
How to track user engagement on Facebook? The goal is to monitor and count engagement for each individual user—tracking the number of likes, comments, and shares, and identifying which specific posts they interacted with
The goal is to monitor and count engagement for each individual user—tracking the number of likes, comments, and shares, and identifying which specific posts they interacted with.

Facebook doesn't offer tracking on an individual user level. You can get aggregated insights data though, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v20.0/insights
